# 400Mbps Broadband, multiple static ips, single wan switch

Tags: networking, router, switch, static-ip, broadband

We just upgraded our bandwidth to 400Mbps, and of course, the ISP has provided us with a Cisco optic fiber switch, that has a single "out"/WAN port.

Current config

```
1.1.1.0/30 as provided by the ISP, soon to be /29
```

right now i can setup a router with ip
`1.1.1.2` `gw 1.1.1.1` and i don't care about multiple static ip's.
The router's dhcp would broadcast it's own class to the employees, which are happy to be able to navigate.

`WHEN /29`

Need to:

- Setup 3 vlans
- MAC filtering is optional, i'm not a big fan... but could be required.
- connect 3 servers and the LAN on different ip's
- setup port forwarding on the LAN's assigned external ip, in order to be able to access dvr's, server's management etc...
- setup failover between the 2 ISP's we have
- setup load balancing (optional)

HowTO... without physical appliance (if possible).
If not, please provide a router/switch recommendation. (I'm not looking to buy clothes, so i believe it's a fair question which expects an answer based on user knowledge and experience with this type of bandwidth). Plus, i'm not the one buying it, it's the company, and i need to provide a decent solution, best fit for performance (NOT ultra, mega professional)...

Currently looking at Cisco RV320 Gigabit Dual WAN, and D-Link DSR 1000N.

If there are details that i need to ask from our ISP, what are they?
If i'm asking in the wrong place... Please point me in the right direction.

Comment: First off, a /30 is not what you want - while it comprises 4 IP's, it only comprises 2 useable IP's - are you sure they did not configure a /30 on the WAN interface (ie your end, their end, broadcast and gateway) - which would be a lot more common then pushing a /30 to a LAN ?

Comment: Shopping recommendations are off-topic here - and the information you need is only available from your ISP.  My apologies, but I'm voting to close for that reason.

Comment: @davidgo I do think this is of general interest, as it touches the difference between switch and router

Comment: @eugenrieck - yes, but there is insufficient detail to allow us to discern if a router or switch is required - this information would lie with his ISP, making it unsuitable to ask here. I can think of  a large number of valid permutations - to the point that speculating is pointless.

Answer (score 1):

When approaching this question you have to understand the different layers of networking involved here:

- a switch (as well as your internet line with modems on both sides) basically don't care about IP addresses - they care about packets only, no matter from and to which IP they go
- a router does indeed care very much about IPs - its job is to "sort and forward" the packets by their IP

This implies, that the switch needs no work whatever to manage the transition from a single IP to a subnet (whether a /28, /29 or /30): On a packet level nothing changes.

A routing change is needed, as on the IP level things do not stay the same. But you might not need a physical appliance: Depending on your needs you might be able to use a virtual router or even no new one at all (by keeping your current router for a single IP and VLAN-ing the others directly to their servers).

Providing more detail will allow us to answer the router question in more detail.

Comment: Provided the topic doesn't close, i will come back with more details as soon as i have them. I have to mention that we don't actually have a current router, since they took it and left us with the switch alone. All i have is a linksys to which i installed DDWRT and with some help from the web, i managed to deploy a failover script for the 2 isp's, plus, it's not gigabit. By using a virtual router, do you mean i could plug the existing connection into one of the servers, and route the other ip's from there? Or how exactly do i do it, without a physical appliance?

Comment: @EugenRieck - You left out variables like PPPoE, MAC address filtering, arp table sizes, as well as vlans and gateways - all of which create a much more complex picture which, as I stated earlier - is not amenable to a Superuser Question.

Comment: @davidgo PPPoE is on the outside, so not applicable. The gatway's properties and the other variables do not change - the question is about which secondary changes a primary change implies.

Comment: @EugeneRieck - PPPoE is absolutely applicable - if the service is delivered by the provider over PPPoE - especially if the /30 is routed over it - the end user needs a router, not a switch or hub.  The OP has also substantially edited their question subsequent to my comments as well. At least here, fibre uses PPPoE